# Looking for smarter way to handle multiple version of a value in Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working on Python data manipulation, and have a column with a variety of values that represent same value.

[image]

I did checked the uniques values and they are as
array(['Male', 'male', 'm', 'FEMALE', 'female', 'F', 'M', 'Female'],       dtype=object)

Please suggest how can i replace it to one version.

Below is the code I did try, but there are more such fields, so **looking for smart way.**

```
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].replace(to_replace =["Male", "male", "m", "M"], value ="Male")
#similar code for Female value.
```

Another approach I am using is

```
df['Gender'] = np.where(df['Gender'].str.lower() == 'male', 'Male', df.Gender)
df['Gender'] = np.where(df['Gender'].str.lower() == 'm', 'Male', df.Gender)
df['Gender'] = np.where(df['Gender'].str.lower() == 'female', 'Female', df.Gender)
df['Gender'] = np.where(df['Gender'].str.lower() == 'f', 'Female', df.Gender)
```

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Hey @desertnaut this is a part of Machine Learning, its a Data Preprocessing step from ML, thus added ML as a tag. Could you please elaborate why you think it as irrelevant tag.. probably this wil help me in segregate it in future.

Comment: Understood, but the question is also applicable to a myriad other *contexts* that have absolutely nothing to do with ML. Rule of thumb re tags is this: tags have only to do with the *content* of the question, *not* its context. And since there is nothing specific to ML *in the question* itself, it should not be tagged as such.

Comment: Got it.. So will tag based on the question.. and not based on what and how it is going to use in future. Thanks this helps.

Comment: Exactly - you are very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just 'm' and 'f':

```
pd.Series(['Male','male', 'm', 'Female', 'female', 'f']).str[0].str.lower()
```

Output:

```
0    m
1    m
2    m
3    f
4    f
5    f
dtype: object
```

Like this with your column:

```
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].str[0].str.lower()
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott Boston, will be using this code as it is simple, easy, and anyways later point will be using One Hot Encoding, so better to have short code from initial. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with a nested `numpy.where`,

```
df['Gender']=np.where(df.Gender.str.lower().str.startswith('m'),'Male',np.where(df.Gender.str.lower().str.startswith('f'),'Female',df.Gender))
```

But in your case, the unique entries just comprise of different representations of "Male" and "Female" and no null so the very easy and quick solution for you can be something like this.

```
df['Gender']=np.where(df.Gender.str.lower().str.startswith('m'),'Male','Female')
```

Comment: Thanks @Ritesh Dubey, this code looks good, but for now will be moving with the shorter code provided by Scott. But anyways its a good learning fo me to have various ways to write or solve a problem. Thanks a lot again.